# chrome extension - getting the last url instead of current

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm getting the last visited url instead of the current one. (when i go to site.com and after that to site2.com, the url I get is 'site.com' and after I refresh site2.com I'm getting the right one.

Based on the answers here:
[Google Chrome Extension get page information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871309/google-chrome-extension-get-page-information)
[Display current URL in a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493995/display-current-url-in-a-chrome-extension)

I've come up with this code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "action.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "unlimitedStorage",
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getUrl"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "getUrl") {
      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
        currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
      });
      sendResponse({data: currentUrl});
    }
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

I've also tried to put this code below directly in content.js and I'm getting an error and in background.js and the url is set to `chrome://extensions/`.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
});
```

what is the right way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried forcing your content script to run after the [document loads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114084/949328)?

Comment: Post your manifest as well.

Comment: @hiattp I've added `"run_at": "document_end"`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Why are you using content scripts? The background page alone is sufficient for this purpose. In addition, when using background/event pages, you can see navigations to all URLs, including `chrome://` URLs. Check out the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) API, in particular the [`onCommitted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCommitted) event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:
**chrome.extension.sendRequest/onRequest** are deprecated. Please, use **[chrome.runtime.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage)/[onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** instead.
Also, whenever possible, prefer **[event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)** over background pages. Most of the time it takes next to nothing to convert a background page to an event page, but can save consideably on resources.

**The problem:**
**chrome.tabs.query** is asynchronous. It means that, when called, it initializes the request and then completes its execution so the next part of your script gets executed. Once the request has completed, the registered callback function is executed. So, this is what happens in your case:

1. You visit `http://www.site1.com`.
2. `chrome.tabs.query({...}, callback)` gets executed (notice the callback has not been executed yet).
3. `sendResponse({data: currentUrl})` gets executed (note that at this point `currentUrl` is not defined).
4. `chrome.tabs.query`'s request completes and the callback function is executed, setting `currentUrl = "http://www.site1.com"` (but only after it is too late).
5. You visit `http://www.site2.com`.
6. `chrome.tabs.query({...}, callback)` gets executed (notice the callback has not been executed yet).
7. `sendResponse({data: currentUrl})` gets executed (note that at this point `currentUrl` still equals `http://www.site1.com` from step 4).
8. `chrome.tabs.query`'s request completes and the callback function is executed, setting `currentUrl = "http://www.site2.com"` (again only after it is too late).

**The solutions:**
**(A)**
Move the logic inside the callback.
(**Note:** Whenever the callback (i.e. `sendResponse`) is going be called asynchronously, it is necessary for the `onMessage` listener to return `true`.)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method && (request.method == "getURL")) {
        if (sendResponse) {
            chrome.tabs.query({
                currentWindow: true,
                active: true
            }, function(tabs) {
                if (tabs.length > 0) {
                    sendResponse({ data: tabs[0].url });
                }
            });
            /* Since 'sendResponse' is to going be called
             * asynchronously, it is necessary to return 'true' */
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        // Do not talk to strangers !!!
    }
});
```

**(B)**
Even simpler in your case, the `sender` parameter of the **[onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** listener, contains the field `tab` which contains the URL info. E.g.:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method && (request.method == "getURL") && sendResponse) {
        sendResponse({ data: sender.tab.url });
    }
});
```

**(C)**
If you only need the URL in the context of the content script, why don't you use `location.href` from within the content script ?

Comment: I must shamefully admit that I actually needed solution `(C)`. But both (A) and (B) are returning undefined no matter how many times I refresh.
PS. I replaced the code from A,B in `background.js`

Comment: It is strange, because I used the exact same code and it worked. Make sure you have replaced your content script's **chrome.extension.sendRequest(...)** with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response) {...});`. Do you see any errors in the console log ?